# Update Attribute with user form input

Tags: arcobjects

I try to use this code to fill attribute of map with my form but it dose not work?

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim mxdoc As IMxDocument = My.ArcMap.Document
        Dim pmap As IMap
        pmap = mxdoc.FocusMap
        Dim penumlayer As IEnumLayer = pmap.Layers
        If pmap.LayerCount > 0 Then
          Dim player As ILayer = penumlayer.Next                                                      
          Do Until player Is Nothing                    
                Dim pflayer As IFeatureLayer
                If TypeOf player Is IFeatureLayer Then
                    pflayer = player
                    Dim pfclass As IFeatureClass = pflayer.FeatureClass
                    pfclass.Value(pfclass.Fields.FindField("TDate")) = TextBox1.Text
                    pfeature.Value(pfeature.Fields.FindField("Proj_Type")) = ComboBox1.Text
                    pfeature.Value(pfeature.Fields.FindField("Utility_Ty")) = ComboBox2.Text
                    pfeature.Value(pfeature.Fields.FindField("Destrict")) = ComboBox3.Text
                    pfeature.Value(pfeature.Fields.FindField("Team_No")) = ComboBox4.Text                                            
                End If
                player = penumlayer.Next
            Loop
        Else                
            MsgBox("NO LAYERS")
        End If     
 End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean ["it does not work"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)?

Comment: Thanks for answer me . the code be like this : pfeature.Value(pfeature.Fields.FindField("Team_No")) = ComboBox4.Text
                   
                    pfeature.Store()
                End If     but also did not store any data in the feature class

Comment: I mean that this code did not store the user data in the attribute of the feature class

Answer (score 3):

You need to commit the changes you have made to the dataset, currently your code is not doing that. All you need to do is call the store method.

So place after the last update and before the `End If` the following line:

```
pfeature.store
```

Comment: the code be like this :